# How to customize bootstrap 4 in reactjs app with reactstrap dependency?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, reactstrap

I start developing a React app with [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/). I followed the Get Started running the following commands :

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start

npm install bootstrap --save
npm install --save reactstrap@next react react-dom
```

Then I can see `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0"` in `package.json`'s `dependencies` and bootstrap/ in my project `node_modules` folder. Well.

Now I would like to change, for instance, the boostrap primary color. Let's start easy :). I have read [Bootstrap 4 Theming](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/) but I don't find any `custom.scss` in my project.

What is the proper way to add and edit bootstrap theme when using reactstrap ? Plus, how do I keep my changes across bootstrap updates since `/node_modules` is in `.gitignore` ?

PS: I am new to web / react development so my apologies if I ask/say anything stupid or obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instructions here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

1. Install Sass: `npm install node-sass --save`
2. Install reactstrap. First bootstrap: `npm install bootstrap --save`. Then reactstrap: `npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom`
3. create your custom bootstrap theme file `src/styles/custom-btsp.scss` and edit as wanted (see [theming v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#importing)).
4. add `import './styles/css/custom.scss';` in `src/index.js`

Done!

Here is an exemple of my `custom-btsp.scss` file:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #ffb800
);

$btn-border-radius: 3000px;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: It is the correct answer! Tks!

Answer (score 2):

You should create SCSS file in your project structure. Include defal=ult bootstrap styles using scss import

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

and after that reassign styles.

But first thing you should to do is adjust your webpack to understand .scss file extensions

Comment: How can we configure webpack to understand .scss file extension ?