# How to pass padding/margin as props in React-Bootstrap components

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to apply margins and paddings with React-Bootstrap as props.

I passed the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io) through but haven't found any mention adding padding or margin in there as it is in official bootstrap docs ([3th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233489/does-bootstrap-have-builtin-padding-and-margin-classes) and [4th](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/)). I know it doesn't support well Bootstrap 4, so tried with both.

I tried to pass params as `p={1}`, `paddingxs={5}` or `mt='1'` but it doesn't recognize any of them. More over tried to find any **Spacing** element in React-Bootstrap folder, but failed.

Paddings and margins work as classnames. But I feel there must be a way to it without Bootstrap classes. There must be a kind of property.

Comment: developers not added spacing functionality on react-bootstrap till now, i prefer to use bootstrap 4 org library for that

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Sam no, i just use bootstrap as classes without react-boorstrap

Comment: @AlexNikonov Is it not possible or have you just never figured it out

Comment: @Sam i tried to find a way but gave up, but there are more than year is passed so some docs might be updated or this fearure might be added, but i'm not sure for this moment

Answer (score 6):

First include bootstrap CSS in your `src/index.js` or `App.js`

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Then you can style your component by passing desired bootstrap CSS class name as `className` prop in React, for example:

```
import React from "react"
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Container fluid className="p-0">
      <SomeOtherComponent />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default MyComponent
```

Above code will add `p-0` CSS class to `Container`.

Reference

[React - How do I add CSS classes to components?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)

[React-Bootstrap - Stylesheets](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets)

Answer (score 4):

You can add margin and padding by using default React's style:

```
const divStyle = {
  marginLeft: '10px',
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

Refrenced from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Comment: yea, i did in that way as i added default bootstrap className='pb-5', my question was how to do it in react-bootstrap only

Comment: It depends on lib itself. Devs may haven't added that kind of features.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: there is no props from React Bootstrap to use margins/paddings.

You can use props for col class, but no for margins.

Example:

```
<Col className="col-6 col-md-3 mb-3 pt-2">
// there you have a Col component from React-Bootstrap 4
// it has some grid system classes, that you can use as props like this:
```

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

```
<Col xs={6} md={3} className="mb-3 pt-2">
// but as you can see, the native classes of Bootstrap 4 like
// mt, mb, pt, pb etc, they have not a props use with
// React-Bootstrap, you have to use them like regular classes
// inside "className"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add className="p-5" to the element. This isn't documented in react-bootstrap but it's in the original Bootstrap 4 documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/#examples

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I'm able to add custom styles to React Bootstrap components by just adding them to the style param. I've put together a short example below, hope this helps.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const styles = {
    myCoolButton: {
        paddingTop: "10vh",
        paddingBottom: "10vh",
        paddingRight: "10vw",
        paddingLeft: "10vw"
    }
}

const ReactButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <Button style={styles.myCoolButton} onClick={()=> {
            console.log("Do something here!")
        }}>Click Me!</Button>
    );
}

export default ReactButton
```

You can also pass custom components (including those from react-bootstrap) [into the styled-components constructor](https://styled-components.com/docs/api) if you prefer to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

None of the jQuery-free implementations of Bootstrap (React Bootstrap, BootstrapVue or ngBootstrap) have implemented utility directives for spacing (`margin`/`padding`), simply because Bootstrap have made it unnecessary in the vast majority of cases, by providing a very intuitive set of [Spacing utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/#how-it-works).

All you need to do is apply the desired class.

---

To apply utility classes selectively, based on responsiveness interval (media queries), you could use a `useMedia` hook, [as demoed here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usemedia-hx7tk?file=/src/index.js).
In a nutshell:

```
const interval = useMedia([
    "(min-width: 1200px)",
    "(min-width: 992px)",
    "(min-width: 768px)",
    "(min-width: 576px)"
  ],
  ["xl", "lg", "md", "sm"],
  "xs"
);
```

(Based on `useMedia` from [useHooks/useMedia](https://usehooks.com/useMedia/)).

You can now reuse this hook throughout your app to add media interval based logic.

Example usages:

```
// interval === 'sm' ? a : b
// ['xs', 'sm'].includes(interval) ? a : b
// negations of the above, etc...
```

**Important:** this particular implementation returns *the **first** matching media query in the list*.

If you need to map various media queries, to an object/map with `true/false` values,  you'll need to modify `getValue` fn to return the entire list, along these lines:

```
const getValue = () => {
  const matches =  mediaQueryLists.map(mql => mql.matches);
  return values.reduce((o, k, i) => ({...o, [k]: matches[i]}), {})
};
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usemedia-n0nxm?file=/src/index.js).
Obviously, you could expand on it and add/remove queries. However, be warned each query adds a separate listener so it could impact performance.

In most cases, the return of the first matching query (first example) is enough.

**Note:** if the above useMedia hook is not enough for your use case, a more robust and heavily tested solution for media-query listeners in JS is [enquire.js](https://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/). It's easy to use, incredibly light and thoroughly tested cross-browser/cross-device. I have no affiliation with it, but I have used it in various projects over the course of more than a decade. In short, I couldn't recommend it more.

---

Back to Bootstrap 4: in order to customize the $spacer sizes, follow the guide provided under Bootstrap's [theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/) as it's actually about more than what we typically call theming (changing colors), it's about overriding default values of Bootstrap's SASS defaults, including responsivenss breakpoints, spacers, number of columns and many, many others. The one you're interested in is [$spacer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#sass-options).
Simply write the overrides into an `.scss` file and import it in your root component. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48872309/1891677).

**Note:** a (simpler and more intuitive) option to customize Bootstrap is to do it visually, using [bootstrap.build](https://bootstrap.build/) but it's typically a few minor versions behind (i.e. Bootstrap is now at `v4.4.1` and the build tool is at `v4.3.0`).
The build customizer provides intuitive controls and real time visualization.
It allows export as `.css` or `.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this out once according to your input and still if face any issue you can reach out.In below we have increased the *.col* padding with *.px-md-5* and then countered then with *.mx-md-n5* on the parent *.row*.

**JSX**:

```
import React from 'react'
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol } from 'mdbreact';

const SpacingPage = () => {
  return (
    <MDBContainer>
      <MDBRow className="mx-md-n5">
        <MDBCol size="6" className="py-3 px-md-5">Custom column padding</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol size="6" className="py-3 px-md-5">Custom column padding</MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>
    </MDBContainer>
  )
}

export default SpacingPage;
```

If you still have any kind of doubt on this then feel free to ask .